# How to send a PCIe read request TLP in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, pci

Just like the title, I wonder if we can issus to the device a PCIe read request TLP manually in Linux.

Is it possible that for this read request TLP, my driver will define the TLP size and TLP TAG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require support in the hardware.

While I don't know of any such hardware, I cannot rule out that it exists.
But in any case, such a function does not appear to be useful for device drivers or even userspace software, so Linux does not have it.